# Arranging Buttons inside a Panel vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to put 25 Buttons inside a Panel in VB.Net 2015 Classic Form Like the Picture but it is not working . could you please help... bellow my code

```
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 25
        newButton = New Windows.Forms.Button
        newButton.AutoSize = True
        newButton.Name = "btnButton" & i
        newButton.Text = "Button " & i
        newButton.Top = i * 5
        newButton.Left = i * 25

        newButton.Size = New Size(95, 70)

        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf ButtonClicked

        Panel1.Controls.Add(newButton)

    Next
```

[image]

Comment: And "not working" means exactly what? You probably get diagonally overlapping buttons. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it works! But they are not arranged as you want. Try to think more about how to manage it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating the buttons, and the problem is that they are not arranged properly so what you need to do is arrange them in rows and columns. here i help you to do this;

Here this snippet will tell you how to arrange them in 5 columns and n rows:

```
Dim x As Integer = 5 ' x co-ordinate of the point
Dim y As Integer = 5 ' y co-ordinate of the point
For i = 1 To 25
    If i Mod 5 = 0 Then ' For starting next row after column
       y += 100 ' 100 is not mandatory change as per size of button
       x = 0
    Else
       x += 100 ' 100 is not mandatory change as per size of button
    End If
    Dim p As Point = New Point(x, y)
    Dim newButton = New Windows.Forms.Button
    newButton.Location = p
    //do the rest of formatting here
    Panel1.Controls.Add(newButton)
Next
```